# Display data on logged user MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem in displaying data of logged user. When i am logged i can go to other pages in my project, but when i need to list the categories of the logged user It is throwing an error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'userId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Here is my code:

**Category Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(int userId)
{
    userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);

    var categories = CategoryRepository.GetCategories(userId);

    return View(categories);
}
```

**SubCategory Controller:**

```
public ActionResult SubCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        var subCategoies = SubCategoryRepository.GetSubCategories(categoryId);
        return View(subCategoies);
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
public static IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories(int userId)
{
    try
    {
        var categories = (from cat in dc.Categories
                          where cat.UserId == userId
                          select cat).ToList();

        return categories;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utility.LogToTrace("CategoryRepository.GetCategories", ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Category","Create")
<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Create SubCategory", "Create", "SubCategory")

@foreach (var item in Model) {

<ul>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
    <li>
        @{ Html.RenderAction("SubCategory", "SubCategory", new {categoryId = item.Id}); }
    </li>
</ul>
}
```

**SubCategoryView:**

```
@model IEnumerable<PasswordCloud.Domain.Models.SubCategory>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

@Html.ActionLink(item.Name,"Index", "Entry", new { subCategoryId = item.SubCategoryId }, null)

}
```

Any help abd suggestions what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the `SubCategory` action in your controller?

Comment: It was listing the category with subcategories fine, but when i added the function with logging user, then showed me this problem.

Comment: Show view SubCategory please

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error , this is caused by this

@Html.ActionLink(item.Name,"Index", "Entry", new { subCategoryId = item.SubCategoryId }, null)

The link is set to go to "Index" action with "UserId" as parameter but you are passing the "SubcategoryID" which is causing this.

Change the name to Userid and Pass the Userid rather than the SubcategoryId.

Hope this helps.